# Azure Pipeline trigger on reopening a PR

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Currently my azure pipeline triggers when I create a new PR in github, however I would like it to trigger also when I reopen a closed PR, I couldn't find any documentation related to this scenario, hence I am unsure if it's possible.

This is the current configuration

```
pr:
  autoCancel: false
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```

Comment: Did you get succeed triggered now? Does below is help for you? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Pipeline trigger on reopening a PR

Yes, it is possible!

Our document does not mentioned very clearly, it only described:

> This configuration triggers a build when any pull request is created,
>   and **when commits come into the source branch of any active pull
>   request**.

In fact, it does **create one new commit** to source branch once you **reopen** the PR. So obviously it can trigger the pipeline.

---

As result show, this is my triggered history by github PR. *(You can see the commit id was changed)*

[image]

And here is the operations history in github. You can see the `PR reopen` trigger the pipeline successfully.

[image]